# Derivative of a function of ordered variables

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, order-theory, vector-spaces, derivations

Can I differentiate
$$(\pmb{y}^o - (\pmb{x}\cdot\pmb{a})^o)^\top(\pmb{y}^o - (\pmb{x}\cdot\pmb{a})^o)$$ with respect to $\pmb{a}$? (I want to minimize the expression with respect to $\pmb{a}$.)

Here, $\pmb{y}^o$ means the ordered vector of $\pmb{y}$. For example, if $\pmb{y} = (2,9,1)^\top$, then $\pmb{y}^o = (1,2,9)^\top$ and $\pmb{x}\cdot\pmb{a} = (a_1x_1, \ldots, a_nx_n)^\top$.

**Try:** I wrote the vector $(\pmb{x}\cdot\pmb{a})^o$ as $\pmb{R}\pmb{x}\cdot\pmb{a}$, where $\pmb{R}$ is a matrix that keeps record of the orders. For the above example, it would be $$\pmb{R}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then I can differentiate the expression w.r.t. $\pmb{a}$. However, the result comes in terms of $\pmb{R}$, which is unknown. (The solution for $\pmb{a}$, that minimizes the given expression, should come in terms of $\pmb{x}$ and $\pmb{y}$.)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: This function is differentiable at any $a$ were sorting does not need a tie-break, i.e. where all entries are pairwise different (that's exactly where the map $a\mapsto a^0$ is differentiable).

Comment: Thanks, @Dirk, under your assumption, how to differentiate it?

Comment: As you said: Just treat the matrix R that does the rearrangement as constant - but you should probably treat it as R(xa).

Comment: But the solution for $\pmb{a}$, that minimizes the given expression, comes in terms of $\pmb{R}$, which is unknown in general. That was the problem I was facing. Please see the last line of the question.

Comment: If you have $a$ (the point at which you differentiate) and $x$, then you know $R$. And you need that there are no entries in $ax$ (the elementwise product) which are equal. Bu maybe I miss something…

Comment: I think, the differentiable function is not continuous, so, you will have like $n!$ different solutions!